# Cambiar input type="radio" por input type="image" + php

Tags: php, javascript, html

buen dia, actualmente uso el input type radio con el metodo post para obtener una informacion:

```
<td class="borrar">
                    <form method="post" action="location.reload()" name="eliminado">
                    <input  type="radio" name="eliminado" onclick="document.forms.prueba.submit()" value="<?php echo $data['cedula']?>"> </td>
```

y lo recibo en php asi:

```
 if(isset($_POST['eliminado'])) 

        { $del = $_POST['eliminado'];

        }  else {$del = '';
            }


    if($del != "" ) 

      {$deleting = "Update resultados set borrado='".$del."' WHERE cedula = '".$del."';";

        $deleting2=mysqli_query($con,$deleting) or die ("Location: ../error.php");

            }  else {};
```

sin embargo desearía no usar el "radio" sino la imagen de una papelera, no obstante cuando hago este cambio no completa la accion borrar.

```
<td class="borrar">
       <form method="post" action="location.reload()" name="eliminado">
       <input  type="image"  src="../imagen/papelera.png" name="eliminado" onclick="document.forms.prueba.submit()" value="<?php echo $data['cedula']?>"> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendí queres que,al hacer click en una imagen se elimine de la base de datos un registro.
Para resolver tu problema probaría poniendo un input escondido.Yo lo haria así:

```
<td class="borrar">
  <form method="post" action="location.reload()" name="eliminado">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['cedula']; ?>" name="cedula">
   <input  type="image"  src="../imagen/papelera.png" onclick="document.forms.prueba.submit()"> 
  </form>
</td>
```

Y en Php:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE resultados SET borrado=eliminado WHERE cedula = "'.$_POST['cedula'].'"";

    $query = mysqli_query($con,$deleting) or die ("Location: ../error.php");
```

> - Te falto cerrar la etiqueta form.
> - No es recomendable los input:image tengan un value.
> - En este caso no es necesario el isset en php, el campo hidden se debería enviar siempre, aunque si por seguridad queres hacerlo esta bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias Gracias